# JQuery object HTML maximum?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

Say we have an ajax call to a server as such :

```
  1 var jSonCall = 
  2  $.ajax({
  3    url: 'http://some_url.com/some_endpoint'
  4  }).success(function(response) {
  5      $(response).appendTo($('.some_div'));
  6  });
  7 return jSonCall;
```

And in chrome I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in the linked jquery file, supposedly caused by line 4.

Say also that I check the response from the request in the Chrome's network tab and discover that the response was 18,000 lines of html (*edit: +150,000 characters). Is it possible that the parameter 'response' (jquery object that should be the bookoos of html), has truncated this somewhere, and that it can only can hold so much html? If so, does anyone know what the hard limitation is (maximum characters or so)?

Comment: You have 2 `{` and 3 `}` in your code

Comment: try truncating the response in 1/2 at server and see what happens if concerned about amount of data. `lines` not very precise measurement unit

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}`

```
var jSonCall = 
  $.ajax({
     url: 'http://some_url.com/some_endpoint'
  }).success(function(response) {
      $(response).appendTo($('.some_div'));
  });
  return jSonCall;
```

Edit :
try :

```
var jSonCall =
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://some_url.com/some_endpoint'
    }).success(function(response) {
        $('.some_div').html(response); //don't make jquery parse the html
    });
return jSonCall;
```

this way you don't have to worry about jQuery parsing the response's html first (`$(response)`).

Comment: Your right. I just edited the question. However that was only a problem with copying the code on to stackoverflow. The actual code doesn't have this problem, and still provides the error. I'm still curious to hear about the possibility of maximums on jq objects.

Comment: It's most likely caused by some syntax error or encoding in the html, using .html() won't make jquery parse it

Comment: you could try to parse it as json and use json_encode server-side.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the JavaScript VM, but in general, there is no hard limit, and the maximum length of a string is defined by the available JSVM heap.